# NetworkX to Gephi different node sizes ignored?

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I want to store different node sizes from a network graph to a gephi file.

According to documentation smth like this should do the cheese:

```
k = 0
for node in G.nodes():
    if (k==0):
         G.node[node]['viz'] = {'size': 200}
         k = 1
    else:
         G.node[node]['viz'] = {'size': 180}

nx.write_gexf(G, "file.gexf")
```

Somehow, only the first node size is considered in Gephi with a size of 200 and the rest is set to the smallest possible size in Gephi (i.e. it ignored the `180`).
So my conclusion: It is not possible to store different node sizes in one graph for Gephi?

Answer (score 1):

That's because there can only be one `size` parameter in a node graph be set. Usually it takes the highest size value as parameter.